# Youtube in UiWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, youtube

I'm getting the URL of the youtube video with this:

```
NSString *currentYouTubeVid = [youTubeWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"function getURL() {var player = document.getElementById('player'); var video = player.getElementsByTagName('video')[0]; return video.getAttribute('src');} getURL();"];
```

This give me this address:

http://r5---sn-uxanug5-coxe.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?sparams=id%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Cratebypass%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&fexp=907050%2C930813%2C916807%2C916611%2C936910%2C936913%2C907231%2C921090&app=youtube_mobile&source=youtube&key=yt5&itag=18&upn=Z8Hh3zpeVwM&ms=au&signature=1E59024805944173684C36996EDB75B8523ADF74.D1BD60DB4276262A08B00FB3A6CF3CFD56B95754&ratebypass=yes&ipbits=0&expire=1389929407&dnc=1&id=7ee5d672b87516cc&mt=1389909046&sver=3&yms=iPABvX0BA-A&mv=m&el=watch&ip=124.191.169.135&cpn=k3p_cmT1D3NyIEk

Is there any way to shorten this address and get something like:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fuXWcrh1Fsw

Thanks if you can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the UIWebView content is loaded, you can view/get its URL with:

```
NSLog(@"WEB VIEW URL: %@", youTubeWebView.request.URL.absoluteString);
```

The result I get in the console is:

```
2014-01-16 17:37:07.014 WebViewer[77010:70b] WEB VIEW URL: http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=IKi0C22S5qo
```

The reason you are seeing the long extended string with your call is due to the fact that the site is actually triggering more URL loads after the original page is loaded. I tested the code above in the `- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView` method. That method gets called multiple times on the same page whenever a new URL is loaded, despite the fact that you are still on the same page.

Regardless of the fact that it is called multiple times, that `youTubeWebView.request.URL.absoluteString` remains the same.